# Long press edit text with a drop down menu

Tags: android, android-edittext

If the user long press an `EditText` widget, I want to show some suggestions in drop down menu like *Bold*, *Italic*, etc. that the user can select from. For example, if the user selects *Bold* from the drop down menu, the whole text entered in the `EditText` widget should become bold. How can I implement this?

Comment: what have your tried?

Comment: Because you haven't shown your effort in implementing this problem. Because your questions doesn't answer to the question "What have you tried?"

Comment: I know about AutoComplete textview but it only displays the suggestions.But there should be an option to write something after selecting one of the name.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are looking for [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html).

> *An editable text view that shows completion suggestions automatically
>   while the user is typing. The list of suggestions is displayed in a
>   drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the
>   content of the edit box with.*

You should read [AutoCompleteTextView Example](http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/tag/autocompletetextview-in-android-with-example/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for AutocompleteTextView. Please see the below example

[AutoCompleteTextView][1]

http://www.javatpoint.com/android-autocompletetextview-example